# Recursive category list table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How can I make recursive categories, like this:

```
computer 
computer > Lenovo
computer > Lenovo > p250
Electronic 
Electronic > Lise
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I setted my models like that:
I have CategoryTable that has CategoryParentId. İf one row has CategoryParentId=0 it is first category. 
here is my function

```
    private void GetSubTree(IList<Page> allCats, Page parent, List<CategoryItemModel> items)
    {
        var subCats = allCats.Where(c => c.CategoryParentID == parent.ID);
        foreach (var cat in subCats)
        {
            //add this category
            items.Add(new CategoryItemModel { ID = cat.Id, Title = parent.Title + " >> " + cat.Title });
            //recursive call in case your have a hierarchy more than 1 level deep
            GetSubTree(allCats, cat, items);
        }
    }
```

Comment: bana bunun html halini atabilirmisin :)

Comment: html tarafında sıkıntı çekiyorum

Comment: birde bunu retur view de nasıl gösterebiliriz yardımın için teşekkür ederim